# Spring @ModelAttribute and @SessionAttribute behaviour

Tags: spring, session, behavior, modelattribute

What is the best way to use `SessionAttributes` and `ModelAttributes` together? When I use, for example, a tagged `ModelAttribute` method and the `SessionAttribute` on the class, then the POJO is added to session, but in other controller that uses the same name for this kind of `ModelAttribute` then it does not retrieve the one I want but takes the one present in the session.

Then, what is the best way to manage the behaviour of `ModelAttributes` with `SessionAttributes`?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have done with the model in the session (I assume you just want to use that 'model in session' in specific Controller only) you have to set `mySessionStat.setComplete()` where in the parameter you declare `SessionStatus mySessionStat`

see:
[SessionStatus api docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/bind/support/SessionStatus.html)